# Where should I put the extension folder

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I downloaded an extension from gnome-shell extensions site.

The file was a zip and I extracted it, now I have a folder with all the extensions files.
What's next? where should I put it?

Comment: What's the file meant for? Mention it in your question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 directories where you can put your extensions, one for manually installed ones and the other one for automatically installed ones.
You should not touch this last one, and you should put everything in:
`/home/[USERNAME]/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`.

The one you should not touch is: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`.

After this, you should activate the extension from tweaks or the extensions app.